# System keeps registering key presses I do not press - Linux 4.13

Tags: ubuntu, elementary-os, software-updates, keyboard-event

I am on elementaryOS (which is based on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS). After latest kernel update, key repeat stopped working. I mean the behaviour which types 'ffffffff' when I hold the 'f' key. I discovered, using xev, that my system is registering key presses constantly, even when I do not press, move or touch anything at all. I am also not able to login into a tty, because it types in '^@' into my login and password every second or so. xev reports this event:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
root 0x2c8, subw 0x0, time 161832, (322,168), root:(1193,635),
state 0x0, keycode 221 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I tried suggested solutions in a [similiar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519239/linux-whats-the-source-of-keypress-event-with-keycode-255), but nothing helped. Any clues?

Comment: Seems like a stuck key. WD-40

Comment: I do not see anything stuck, and WD-40 is not available in my country, as I live in the Czech republic, Europe.

Comment: I can get WD-40 here in Portugal...or something similar.

Comment: I'll look into the alternatives. Meanwhile, any way to detect which key is being stuck? What is the 221 keycode? It even says NoSymbol. If I type the 'f' letter for example, it prints it directly into the output, that I pushed the 'f' letter.

Comment: 221 it should be  ] }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be caused by a bug in the kernel module `peaq_wmi` as unloading it fixes the issue. This bug was intruced by the 4.13 kernel update. More people have had it. More info here: [Arch linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230340), and the solution is here: [unix & linux autorepeat does not work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395535/autorepeat-does-not-work/416363#416363).